# How to capture afterprint event from a PDF page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Why don't the

```
window.addEventListener('afterprint', (event) => {
  console.log('After print');
});

window.onafterprint = (event) => {
  console.log('After print');
};
```

commands work on PDF pages? I made a code to send a message to my background.js after print, the code works perfectly on all chrome pages, but on PDF pages they just don't work, and they don't return any kind of error?

```
"permissions": ["tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
 "content_scripts":[
    {
       "js": ["popup.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
   }
```

Comment: What are PDF pages? Is it with the PDF open in chrome? If so, the extension won't work there.

Comment: https://www.caceres.mt.gov.br/fotos_institucional_downloads/2.pdf
Pages like this. The window.print() command works, but the two I mentioned in the question don't

Answer (score 0):

PDf viewers like Acrobat for browsers or modern replacements like Chromium's (Brave Edge etc.) using inbuilt Foxit Skia extension, are Integrated Standalone Binaries.

Here we can see an alternate one, both files are web url entries, but the principle is EXACTLY the same it is either standalone, plugged-in or integrated.

Left is Windows Trident inbuilt System - - - - - - -        Right is Mozilla web browser
[image]

What you can note in this case is there is NO pdf print just save as PDF. It is not the fact that there's no print function in this example, to respond it is the fact ALL are secured against outside tampering, as they are running in the clients system.

No feedback at all, once a PDF is in a PDF editor/viewer, rather than the HTML editor we call a browser.

Comment: I was able to use several commands on these types of pages, including Window.print(). I also managed to use chrome.runtime.sendMessage, however, I didn't understand why these mentioned commands don't work inside window.onafterprint();

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject, I honestly didn't understand if this was an answer to my question! I'll keep studying more about it, anyway... Thanks for trying to clarify!

Comment: Thanks! So apparently it only supports some commands, by the way I'll have to think of some solution to get around this problem of mine